# Aggregation Framework, Sort by array size including empty

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get a list of publications sort by number of tags. I've get some stuff working but the `$unwind` operator make disappear the publications with zero tags. I've tried to add a place holder to bypass that without success:

```
Publication.collection.aggregate(
    { "$project" => { tags: { "$push" => "holder" } } }, 
    { "$unwind" => '$tags' }, 
    { "$group" => { _id: '$_id', count: { "$sum" => 1 } } }, 
    { "$sort" => { count: 1 } }
  )
```

I got:

```
failed with error 15999: "exception: invalid operator '$push'"
```

Documents exemples:

```
{ _id: '1', tags: ['b','c'] } 
{ _id: '2', tags: ['a'] } 
{ _id: '3' }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show an example document or two, please?

Comment: Sure: `{_id: '1', tags: ['b','c']}`, `{_id: '2', tags: ['a']}` `{_id: '3'}`

Comment: Just edited the question with examples, anyone have a clue? Still working on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `$push` in a `$project` pipeline stage; it's only for the `$group` stage. Unfortunately you can't just add a constant to the end of all the tags arrays in your aggregation pipeline.

This is inelegant, but I'd add a placeholder to all tags arrays in your collection itself:

```
db.collection.update({}, {$addToSet: {tags: null}}, false, true)
```

Then subtract 1 from the counts at the end of your pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    { '$unwind' : '$tags' },
    { '$group' : { _id: '$_id', count: { '$sum' : 1 } } },
    { $project: { _id: true, count: { '$subtract': [ '$count', 1 ] } } },
    { '$sort' : { count: 1 } }
)
```

Vote for https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9334 to get a better method in the future.

Comment: Ok, I've voted! Sure, that a shame that we can't do it directly in the aggregation framework, seems pretty narrow what we can achieve with the aggregation framework finally.